# How do I convert a PIL Image into a NumPy array?

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, numpy-ndarray

How do I convert a PIL `Image` back and forth to a NumPy array so that I can do faster pixel-wise transformations than PIL's `PixelAccess` allows? I can convert it to a NumPy array via:

```
pic = Image.open("foo.jpg")
pix = numpy.array(pic.getdata()).reshape(pic.size[0], pic.size[1], 3)
```

But how do I load it back into the PIL `Image` after I've modified the array? `pic.putdata()` isn't working well.

Comment: Note that `pic.size[0]` and `pic.size[1]` should be swapped (ie. `reshape(pic.size[1], pic.size[0], 3)`), since `size` is `width x height` or `x * y`, while matrix ordering is `rows x columns`.

Answer (score 465, accepted):

You're not saying how exactly `putdata()` is not behaving. I'm assuming you're doing

```
>>> pic.putdata(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...blablabla.../PIL/Image.py", line 1185, in putdata
    self.im.putdata(data, scale, offset)
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

This is because `putdata` expects a sequence of tuples and you're giving it a numpy array. This

```
>>> data = list(tuple(pixel) for pixel in pix)
>>> pic.putdata(data)
```

will work but it is very slow.

As of PIL 1.1.6, the ["proper" way to convert between images and numpy arrays](https://web.archive.org/web/20081225061956/http://effbot.org/zone/pil-changes-116.htm) is simply

```
>>> pix = numpy.array(pic)
```

although the resulting array is in a different format than yours (3-d array or rows/columns/rgb in this case).

Then, after you make your changes to the array, you should be able to do either `pic.putdata(pix)` or create a new image with `Image.fromarray(pix)`.

Comment: That page lists `numpy.asarray(pic)` as the "proper" way to convert, not `numpy.array(pic)`. As per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415741/numpy-array-vs-asarray) `array` will make a copy whereas `asarray` will not (but then the `asarray` result will be read-only).

Comment: The second answer is better.

Comment: Type check warns: 'Expected type 'Union[ndarray, Iterable, int, float]', got 'Image' instead'

Answer (score 357):

Open `I` as an array:

```
>>> I = numpy.asarray(PIL.Image.open('test.jpg'))
```

Do some stuff to `I`, then, convert it back to an image:

```
>>> im = PIL.Image.fromarray(numpy.uint8(I))
```

Source: [Filter numpy images with FFT, Python](http://barnesc.blogspot.com/2007/09/filter-numpy-images-with-fft-python.html)

If you want to do it explicitly for some reason, there are pil2array() and array2pil() functions using getdata() on [this page](http://bradmontgomery.blogspot.com/2007/12/computing-correlation-coefficients-in.html) in correlation.zip.

Comment: @ArditS.: Did you `import Image` first?  Do you have PIL installed?

Comment: Is the `uint8` conversion necessary?

Comment: you might need to use numpy.copy to have I be editable: `I = numpy.copy(numpy.asarray(Image.open('test.jpg')))`

Comment: Thanks for this, I was using np.array(image.getdata(),...) which is incredibly slow compared to this.

Comment: @NeilTraft No, sorry.  Note that if your image is a float array from 0 to 1, you need to scale it first: `Image.fromarray(J*255)`

Comment: `numpy.asarray(Image.open(filename))` seems to work for .jpg images but not for .png.  The result displays as `array(<PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=LA size=500x500 at 0x3468198>, dtype=object)`.  There seem to be no obviously-named methods of the `PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile` object for solving this.  Guess I should ask this as a new question but it's very relevant to this thread. Anybody understand what's going wrong here?

Comment: @Rebs: here's the reason *why* this is so much faster: `getdata()` returns a sequence like object (http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata), but a pillow image implements the `__array_interface__` which `numpy` can use to access the raw bytes of an image without having to pass through an iterator (see https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/730cf93c32ffb747c018afffe597ef9ae264a20a/PIL/Image.py#L633 and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html). You can even just use `numpy.array(PIL.Image.open('test.jpg'))`

Comment: @jez Check if the Image object is closed before you convert it to numpy. The same happened to me and I found I closed the image object somewhere.

Comment: @jez I use `numpy.asarray(PIL.Image.open('test.png').convert('RGB'))` which works for even for .png images

Answer (score 130):

I am using Pillow 4.1.1 (the successor of PIL) in Python 3.5. The conversion between Pillow and numpy is straightforward.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
im = Image.open('1.jpg')
im2arr = np.array(im) # im2arr.shape: height x width x channel
arr2im = Image.fromarray(im2arr)
```

One thing that needs noticing is that Pillow-style `im` is column-major while numpy-style `im2arr` is row-major. However, the function `Image.fromarray` already takes this into consideration. That is, `arr2im.size == im.size` and `arr2im.mode == im.mode` in the above example.

We should take care of the HxWxC data format when processing the transformed numpy arrays, e.g. do the transform `im2arr = np.rollaxis(im2arr, 2, 0)` or `im2arr = np.transpose(im2arr, (2, 0, 1))` into CxHxW format.

Comment: This is about the cleanest example, including import statements (thanks for that detail). Let's vote this answer up to increase visibility.

Comment: I found that when I converted a PIL drawn image to a numpy array, when using matplotlib imshow on the array, it showed it upside down requiring a `np.flipud` to fix. Although my PIL image was created from scratch using `ImageDraw.Draw`. I think one must be careful where the origin of their coordinates comes from.

Comment: Bless you!! I have been looking for this answer for half a day. It solves my problem of restoring the original axis after of the plot image to the original one.

Answer (score 38):

You need to convert your image to a numpy array this way:

```
import numpy
import PIL

img = PIL.Image.open("foo.jpg").convert("L")
imgarr = numpy.array(img)
```

Comment: This way of conversion retains the image but results in a loss of colors. Anyway to avoid the color loss?

Comment: @moondra If I understand your question, you can replace `.convert("L") ` by `.convert("RGB")`

Comment: "L" produces the image in grayscale

Answer (score 35):

Convert **`Numpy to PIL`** image  and **`PIL to Numpy`**

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def pilToNumpy(img):
    return np.array(img)

def NumpyToPil(img):
    return Image.fromarray(img)
```

Answer (score 3):

The example, I have used today:

```
import PIL
import numpy
from PIL import Image

def resize_image(numpy_array_image, new_height):
    # convert nympy array image to PIL.Image
    image = Image.fromarray(numpy.uint8(numpy_array_image))
    old_width = float(image.size[0])
    old_height = float(image.size[1])
    ratio = float( new_height / old_height)
    new_width = int(old_width * ratio)
    image = image.resize((new_width, new_height), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    # convert PIL.Image into nympy array back again
    return array(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image is stored in a Blob format (i.e. in a database) you can use the same technique explained by Billal Begueradj to convert your image from Blobs to a byte array.

In my case, I needed my images where stored in a blob column in a db table:

```
def select_all_X_values(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT ImageData from PiecesTable")    
    rows = cur.fetchall()    
    return rows
```

I then created a helper function to change my dataset into np.array:

```
X_dataset = select_all_X_values(conn)
imagesList = convertToByteIO(np.array(X_dataset))

def convertToByteIO(imagesArray):
    """
    # Converts an array of images into an array of Bytes
    """
    imagesList = []

    for i in range(len(imagesArray)):  
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(imagesArray[i])).convert("RGB")
        imagesList.insert(i, np.array(img))

    return imagesList
```

After this, I was able to use the byteArrays in my Neural Network.

```
plt.imshow(imagesList[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I can vouch for **svgtrace**, I found it both super simple and relatively fast. Find it here: https://pypi.org/project/svgtrace/

This  is how I used it:

```py
from svgtrace import trace

asset_path = 'image.png'
save_path = 'traced_image.svg'

Path(save_path).write_text(trace(asset_path), encoding='utf-8')
```

It took an average of 3 seconds for a 1080x1080px image on my machine. (MacBook Pro 2017)

Answer (score -4):

```
def imshow(img):
    img = img / 2 + 0.5     # unnormalize
    npimg = img.numpy()
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1, 2, 0)))
    plt.show()
```

You can transform the image into numpy 
by parsing the image into numpy() function after squishing out the features( unnormalization)

Comment: This is for conversion between numpy and a tensor in e.g. PyTorch. This question is about PIL.