# How would I scale a 2-dimensional array in python?

Tags: python, matrix

I'm not sure how to go about scaling a 2-dimensional array.  Given the array below, whose dimensions are 8x10, say I needed to scale it to 5x6 -- I've looked for concrete examples on wikipedia, but without much grounding in matrix math I'm a bit lost.  If someone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it!

```
[
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
]
```

Comment: When you say scale, what exactly do you mean? Treat it as a picture?

Comment: Scaling has a specific meaning with regards to matrices (namely, it's a particular affine transformation), which does *not* change the size of the matrix. Thus I guess you're referring to something else here, but it's not clear what that is.

Comment: Yah, treat it like a picture.  I think this is where my problems finding a solution have stemmed because matrix transformation seems to be a bit different.  I'd like to "preserve" in some sense the data contained within while scaling down or up arbitrarily

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since your array looks like it is a binary image of a lower case 'a' letter, I'm guessing that you mean scaling in the image sense.

To do that, I would recommend using the `imresize` function in scipy.misc (which is taken from PIL, I believe). Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imresize

img = np.array([
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
])
newimg = imresize(img, (6,5))
```

and newimg is then

```
array([[  0,   0, 255, 255,   0],
       [  0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255,   0,   0, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

which isn't perfect, but you can change the 255's to 1's easily enough. Also, if you get the development version of Scipy, currently version 9, then you have [some other parameters](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/misc.html)(scroll down to imresize - no anchor) that you can input to imresize such as the interpolation method and PIL mode.

Comment: Why use scipy when just using PIL directly makes more sense?

Comment: Wow, I totally figured it would a hack to use PIL directly, but maybe that's the best way to go

Comment: @martineau, maybe because you want to use the result back in scipy? That was my thought anyway.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, use a library!

[PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) has functions for resizing images, assuming that's the kind of scaling you're after.  To convert your list of lists to a PIL image, first convert it to a numpy array, [then to PIL format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384759/pil-and-numpy). After you're done, you can reverse the process to get a list of lists again (if you really want).