# What is the difference between np.array() and np.asarray()?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is the difference between NumPy's [`np.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array) and [`np.asarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html#numpy.asarray)? When should I use one rather than the other? They seem to generate identical output.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Since other questions are being redirected to this one which ask about `asanyarray` or [other array creation routines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html), it's probably worth having a brief summary of what each of them does.

The differences are mainly about when to return the input unchanged, as opposed to making a new array as a copy.

[`array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) offers a wide variety of options (most of the other functions are thin wrappers around it), including flags to determine when to copy. A full explanation would take just as long as the docs (see [Array Creation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html#arrays-creation), but briefly, here are some examples:

Assume `a` is an `ndarray`, and `m` is a `matrix`, and they both have a `dtype` of `float32`:

- `np.array(a)` and `np.array(m)` will copy both, because that's the default behavior.
- `np.array(a, copy=False)` and `np.array(m, copy=False)` will copy `m` but not `a`, because `m` is not an `ndarray`.
- `np.array(a, copy=False, subok=True)` and `np.array(m, copy=False, subok=True)` will copy neither, because `m` is a `matrix`, which is a subclass of `ndarray`.
- `np.array(a, dtype=int, copy=False, subok=True)` will copy both, because the `dtype` is not compatible.

Most of the other functions are thin wrappers around `array` that control when copying happens:

- [`asarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html): The input will be returned uncopied iff it's a compatible `ndarray` (`copy=False`).
- [`asanyarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asanyarray.html): The input will be returned uncopied iff it's a compatible `ndarray` or subclass like `matrix` (`copy=False`, `subok=True`).
- [`ascontiguousarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html): The input will be returned uncopied iff it's a compatible `ndarray` in contiguous C order (`copy=False`, `order='C')`.
- [`asfortranarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asfortranarray.html): The input will be returned uncopied iff it's a compatible `ndarray` in contiguous Fortran order (`copy=False`, `order='F'`).
- [`require`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.require.html): The input will be returned uncopied iff it's compatible with the specified requirements string.
- [`copy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html): The input is always copied.
- [`fromiter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html): The input is treated as an iterable (so, e.g., you can construct an array from an iterator's elements, instead of an `object` array with the iterator); always copied.

There are also convenience functions, like [`asarray_chkfinite`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray_chkfinite.html) (same copying rules as `asarray`, but raises `ValueError` if there are any `nan` or `inf` values), and constructors for subclasses like `matrix` or for special cases like record arrays, and of course the actual [`ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) constructor (which lets you create an array directly out of strides over a buffer).

Comment: Just to correct, Numpy's ndarray now has float64 as default dtype.

Comment: In the first section, in the 4th point, you actually meant ---  *"`np.array(a, dtype=int, copy=False, subok=True)` **and `np.array(m, dtype=int, copy=False, subok=True)`** will copy both, because the `dtype` is not compatible."* --- right? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 319):

The [definition of `asarray`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/bcbed877f42ed6e9b01b2125134db4b6395f1d9d/numpy/core/numeric.py#L413-481) is:

```
def asarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
```

So it is like `array`, except it has fewer options, and `copy=False`. `array` has `copy=True` by default.

The main difference is that `array` (by default) will make a copy of the object, while `asarray` will not unless necessary.

Comment: So when should we use each?  If creating an array from scratch, which is better, `array([1, 2, 3])` or `asarray([1, 2, 3])`?

Comment: @endolith: `[1, 2, 3]` is a Python list, so a copy of the data must be made to create the `ndarary`. So use `np.array` directly instead of `np.asarray` which would send the `copy=False` parameter to `np.array`. The `copy=False` is ignored if a copy must be made as it would be in this case. If you benchmark the two using `%timeit` in IPython you'll see a difference for small lists, but it hardly matters which you use for large lists.

Comment: That makes sense per the method names too: "asarray": Treat this as an array (inplace), i.e., you're sort of just changing your view on this list/array. "array": Actually convert this to a new array.

Comment: how about `np.asanyarray`?

Comment: @Lee: `asarray` always returns an `ndarray`. `asanyarray` will return a subclass of `ndarray` if that is what was passed to it. For example, an `np.matrix` is a subclass of `ndarray`. So `np.asanyarray(np.matrix(...))` returns the same matrix, whereas `np.asarray(np.matrix(...))` converts the matrix to an `ndarray`.

Comment: In your example, `np.asanyarray(np.matrix(...))` returns the original matrix (or view), whereas `np.asarray(np.matrix(...))` makes a new copy as the `ndarray` returned?

Comment: @Lee: Yes, `np.asarray(np.matrix(...))` returns a copy. You can easily test this -- Let `x = np.matrix([1])` and `y = np.asarray(np.matrix([1]))`. Set `y[0,0] = 100`. If `y` is a view of `x` then assignment to `y` would modify `x`. But you'll find that `x` remains the same. So you can conclude that `y` is a copy of `x`.

Comment: When
`arr1 = np.asarray([1,2])`
`arr2 = np.array(arr1)`
`arr3 = np.asarray(arr1)`
, we see the difference as follows:
`arr1 is arr2`
`>> False`
`arr1 is arr3`
`>> True`

Comment: @unutbu in your response to @ endolith's comment, you said "*in IPython you'll see a difference for small lists, but it hardly matters which you use for large lists.*" Shouldn't it be other way around? I mean it should be "*in IPython you'll see a difference for **larger** lists, but it hardly matters which you use for **smaller** lists.*" right?

Answer (score 156):

The difference can be demonstrated by this example:

1. Generate a matrix.

   ```
    >>> A = numpy.matrix(numpy.ones((3, 3)))
    >>> A
    matrix([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
            [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
            [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
   ```
2. Use `numpy.array` to modify `A`. Doesn't work because you are modifying a copy.

   ```
    >>> numpy.array(A)[2] = 2
    >>> A
    matrix([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
            [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
            [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
   ```
3. Use `numpy.asarray` to modify `A`. It worked because you are modifying `A` itself.

   ```
    >>> numpy.asarray(A)[2] = 2
    >>> A
    matrix([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
            [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
            [ 2.,  2.,  2.]])
   ```

Answer (score 15):

The differences are mentioned quite clearly in the documentation of [`array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array) and [`asarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html#numpy.asarray). The differences lie in the argument list and hence the action of the function depending on those parameters.

The function definitions are :

```
numpy.array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order=None, subok=False, ndmin=0)
```

and

```
numpy.asarray(a, dtype=None, order=None)
```

The following arguments are those that may be passed to `array` and **not** `asarray` as mentioned in the documentation :

> copy : bool, optional **If true (default), then the object is copied**.
>   Otherwise, a copy will only be made if `__array__` returns a copy, if
>   obj is a nested sequence, or if a copy is needed to satisfy any of the
>   other requirements (dtype, order, etc.).
>
> subok : bool, optional **If True, then sub-classes will be
>   passed-through**, otherwise the returned array will be forced to be a
>   base-class array (default).
>
> ndmin : int, optional Specifies the **minimum number of dimensions that
>   the resulting array** should have. Ones will be pre-pended to the shape
>   as needed to meet this requirement.

Answer (score 6):

`asarray(x)` is like `array(x, copy=False)`

Use `asarray(x)` when you want to ensure that `x` will be an array before any other operations are done. If `x` is already an array then no copy would be done. It would not cause a redundant performance hit.

Here is an example of a function that ensure `x` is converted into an array first.

```py
def mysum(x):
    return np.asarray(x).sum()
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's understand the difference between `np.array()` and `np.asarray()` with the example:

`np.array()`: Converts input data (list, tuple, array, or another sequence type) to a ndarray and copies the input data by default.

`np.asarray()`: Converts input data to a ndarray but does not copy if the input is already a ndarray.

```py
# Create an array...
arr = np.ones(5);  # array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

```py
# Now I want to modify `arr` with `array` method. Let's see...
np.array(arr)[3] = 200;  # array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

No change in the array because we are modifying a copy of the array, `arr`.

Now, modify `arr` with `asarray()` method.

```py
np.asarray(arr)[3] = 200;  # array([1., 200, 1., 1., 1.])
```

The change occurs in this array because we are working with the original array now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example that can demonstrate the difference.

The main difference is that array will make a copy of the original data and using different object we can modify the data in the original array.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(0.0, 10.2, 0.12)
int_cvr = np.asarray(a, dtype = np.int64)
```

The contents in array (a), remain untouched, and still, we can perform any operation on the data using another object without modifying the content in original array.

Answer (score 0):

#### Difference

1. `np.array()`: Converts input data like list, tuple, etc. to `ndarray` and **copies the input data by default**. This creates redundant object in memory.
2. `np.asarray()`: Converts input data to `ndarray` but **does not copy if the input is already `ndarray`**. This is more memory efficient.

```py
import numpy as np

print("NumPy version:", np.__version__)
```

```
NumPy version: 1.22.3
```

#### Case 1: Using `np.array()` when input is `ndarray`.

```py
# STEP 1: Initialize source.
src1 = np.ones(5)
print("Data type:", type(src1))
print("Values:\n", src1)

# STEP 2: Convert to `ndarray`.
arr1 = np.array(src1)               # np.array() is used.
print("\nData type:", type(arr1))
print("Values:\n", arr1)

# STEP 3: Compare source with converted `ndarray`.
print("\nIs Source & new NumPy array same?\n", src1 is arr1)
```

##### Output

```
Data type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Values:
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

Data type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Values:
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

Is Source & new NumPy array same?
 False
```

#### Case 2: Using `np.asarray()` when input is `ndarray`.

```py
# STEP 1: Initialize source.
src2 = np.ones(5)
print("Data type:", type(src2))
print("Values:\n", src2)

# STEP 2: Convert to `ndarray`.
arr2 = np.asarray(src2)             # np.asarray() is used.
print("\nData type:", type(arr2))
print("Values:\n", arr2)

# STEP 3: Compare source with converted `ndarray`.
print("\nIs Source & new NumPy array same?\n", src2 is arr2)
```

##### Output

```
Data type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Values:
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

Data type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Values:
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

Is Source & new NumPy array same?
 True
```

Hence by comparing two outputs we can conclude that:
When using `np.asarray()` on `ndarray`, the source `ndarray` and converted `ndarray` are **pointing to same object in the memory**.