# How to use the scikit-image greycomatrix() -function in python?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, scikit-image, glcm

I'm trying to compute grey level co-occurrence matrices from images for feature extraction. I'm using [`greycomatrix`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html?highlight=greycomatrix#skimage.feature.greycomatrix) for the task but there seems to be something I don't understand about the process since I'm getting the following error:

> ValueError: buffer source array is read-only

(The full trace can be found below)

### So here's what I've done:

Converting the (PIL) image to grayscale with 8 quantization levels:

```
greyImg = img.convert('L', colors=8)
```

And then compute the glcm matrices:

```
glcm = greycomatrix(greyImg, distances=[1], angles=[0, np.pi/4, np.pi/2], 
                    symmetric=True, normed=True)
```

This results in a rather cryptic error:

> glcm = greycomatrix(img, distances=[1], angles=[0, np.pi/4, np.pi/2], levels=256, symmetric=True, normed=True)
>
> _glcm_loop(image, distances, angles, levels, P)
>
> File "skimage/feature/_texture.pyx", line 18, in skimage.feature._texture._glcm_loop
>
> File "stringsource", line 654, in View.MemoryView.memoryview_cwrapper
>
> File "stringsource", line 349, in View.MemoryView.memoryview._cinit__
>   ValueError: buffer source array is read-only

I've been trying to tingle with the paremeters but I can't seem to figure out, why this happens. What would be the correct way to compute the glcm-matrix?

#### Update

The problem was in the grayscale conversion.
The following changes were required:

```py
import numpy as np

greyImg = np.array(img.convert('L', colors=8))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `greycomatrix` expects a NumPy `ndarray` rather than a PIL `Image` object. You need to convert `greyImg` like this:

```
import numpy as np

greyImg = np.asarray(img.convert('L', colors=8))
```

Comment: And you probably want to read the image using `skimage.io`.  Doing conversion from PIL by hand is brittle.

Comment: Yes, that was my problem. Thank you. However, `np.asarray()` produced the exact same error. `np.array` did the trick.

Comment: Either of them worked fine in my computer. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415741/numpy-array-vs-asarray)