# is there a faster way to create a array of elements of an empty array without using for loops

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

I want to create an array of elements. I can do it using a loop, but i want to know if there is another way, like an `numpy`  function or something to do this in less timme.

this is what i want to do:

```py
def no_loops(y):


   mat = []
   for i in range(5012):
       mat.append(y[i])

   fun = funcion_a(mat)

   return fun
```

The y array is empty. The elements of the array are the solutions of an equation system that scipy will solve. 
I want to change the for loop for something faster.

Comment: ***y** array is empty* - and how is that `y[i]` working in such case? Does not look like working code

Comment: That loop just makes a copy of `y`

Comment: root from scipy optimize needs an empty  array to itarate and find a solution to an non-linear equation system.

Comment: y dosen't exist, all i want to do its to give the index of the values that already have in another function and solve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a new array of a certain size, and want to ignore the very confusing `y` from your sample code, you could do something like this:

```
def no_loops():
    # Create an array of length 5012, all elements of which are zero.
    return funcion_a(numpy.zeros(5012))
```

You could also use [`numpy.empty`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) in this case, but I prefer the determinism of [`numpy.zeros`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html).

If you want to copy the data in `y`, you could explicitly copy using `numpy.array`:

```
def no_loops(y):
   return funcion_a(numpy.array(y[:5012]))
```

You could also investigate using `numpy.asanyarray` if you need to support subclasses of `numpy.array`.  See: [Numpy - array vs asarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415741/numpy-array-vs-asarray)