# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'?

Tags: python, lstm, prediction

can somebody help me, I've been trying to run the script below

```
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, newshape = (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
```

but only to have an error like this

```
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-48-9880c2146f81> in <module>()----> 1 X_train = np.reshape(X_train, newshape = (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

and here is the full script

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

downloads = pd.read_csv('Datatraining.csv')
training_set = downloads.iloc[:, 1:2].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)

X_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(72, len(training_set_scaled)):
    X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-60: i, 0])
    y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i, 0])
    X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)

X_train = np.reshape(X_train, newshape = (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
```

Comment: `X_train` is a list and not an `ndarray`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `X_train` is not a np array but a `list`. You first have to convert your list to a numpy array

```
X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
```

Comment: Is `np.asarray(X_train)` detectably different from `np.array(X_train)`?

Comment: @alaniwi here is a great thread on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52103839/1434626

Comment: asarray is more efficient as it will not make a copy if not required while having less options. In the OP question it would make no difference indeed.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error, I managed to solve it by changing everywhere `X_train` to `x_train`