# Problems using OpenCV imwrite method with image from OpenMV camera

Tags: python, image, opencv, openmv

I am trying to stitch some images taken from my OpenMV H7 camera using OpenCV's stitching algorithm. I ran into the problem that I cannot write or read these images, which made me think that there are some compatibility issues.

To be more exact, I got this error when using the method (cv2.imwrite) itself:

```
  File "main_script_test.py", line 141, in <module>
    cv2.imwrite("/Documents/Cam/Images/image_" + str(images_To_Be_Taken), img)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
```

I have been thinking that maybe there is a way I can turn the image into a NumPy array to make it compatible, but I am not quite sure.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps try converting the image with `np.asarray(img)` and see if that works

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Comment: No worries :) I wrote up my comment as an answer with a bit more detail

Comment: I just saw the image and its a 1D array lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OpenCV's imwrite](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce) is expecting a Mat object, which is an "n-dimensional dense array class". Passing in a `numpy` array of the image data in place of Mat objects, in the case of imwrite() at least, will yield the correct result.

From the documentation linked above:

> So, the data layout in Mat is compatible with the majority of dense
> array types from the standard toolkits and SDKs, such as Numpy
> (ndarray), Win32 (independent device bitmaps), and others, that is,
> with any array that uses steps (or strides) to compute the position of
> a pixel. Due to this compatibility, it is possible to make a Mat
> header for user-allocated data and process it in-place using OpenCV
> functions.

For your code:

```
cv2.imwrite("/Documents/Cam/Images/image_" + str(images_To_Be_Taken), np.asarray(img))
```

Comment: It worked for viewing it, but now it's just a 1D array.

Comment: Looks like we need to reshape. You can call `np.array(img).reshape((y, x))` on the array to convert it back to 2d, with y and x being the dimensions. I'd also suggest using `np.array(img)` instead of `np.asarray(img)` [so the original img is copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415741/what-is-the-difference-between-numpys-array-and-asarray-functions). See if that works