# is there a way to create numpy array from a list of images?

Tags: python, numpy

i'm trying to creat numpy array from my list that contains are 1768 images. this my code:

```
w = []
directory = os.listdir(PATH)
directory = sorted(directory, key=len)
for item in directory:
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(PATH, item))
    w.append(img)
    count+=1
print('w_shape: ', np.array(w, dtype='float32').shape)
```

and when run it, i face with this error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'JpegImageFile'
```

anybody can help me to solve?

Comment: What do you want the resulting array to look like? What should its `shape` be? What problem do you hope to solve by creating the array?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `artificial-intelligence` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because each element of you list is a 'JpegImageFile' which is not compatible with `float()`. To avoid this, add the images directly as arrays to your list.
You can use `np.asarray()` to read the image as a numpy array. Check out the code snippet below:

```
w = []
directory = os.listdir(PATH)
directory = sorted(directory, key=len)
for item in directory:
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(PATH, item))
    w.append(np.asarray(img)) # convert it to an array of floats
    count+=1 
print('w_shape: ', np.array(w, dtype='float32').shape)
```

Note: You can also use `np.array(img)` instead. Check out what the difference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415741/what-is-the-difference-between-numpys-array-and-asarray-functions)