# Convert a PIL image to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I want to convert a PIL image to a numpy array. Numpy's `asarray` function simply puts the image in a 0-dimensional array.

```
(Pdb) p img
<PIL.Image._ImageCrop image mode=RGB size=1024x0 at 0x106953560>
(Pdb) img.getdata()
<ImagingCore object at 0x104c97b10>
(Pdb) np.asarray(img.getdata())
array([], dtype=float64)
(Pdb) np.asarray(img)
array(<PIL.Image._ImageCrop image mode=RGB size=1024x0 at 0x106953560>, dtype=object)
(Pdb) np.asarray(img).shape
()
(Pdb) np.asarray(img, np.uint8)
*** SystemError: error return without exception set
```

The solutions on a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384759/pil-and-numpy) didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `img` has size 1024x0:

> PIL.Image._ImageCrop image mode=RGB size=**1024x0** at 0x106953560

That is an image with 0 height. Therefore, the resultant NumPy array  is empty. To fix, crop the image so that it has a positive width and height.