# Cannot get Image written with cv2 and PIL Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am using python 2.7 with OpenCV and PIL Running on windows 10

I am trying to get an image written with `cv2.imwrite()` like follow Code:

```
  x={{"Some Process On an Image "}}
  #now saving the effects on real image
  cv2.imwrite("temp.png", x)
```

now I am trying to get the text from the same image with `pytesseract`
and need to open the image
with the `PIL` library  within another calss becuase the `pytesseract`
doesnt deal with `cv2` images

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2

if __name__ == '__main__':

     url= Image.open("temp.png")
     cv2.waitKey(200)
     text=pytesseract.image_to_string(url)
     print text
     cv2.waitKey(0)
```

and Gave Me this Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Elie MA\Documents\NetBeansProjects\tesser\src\new_module.py", line 9, in <module>
    text=pytesseract.image_to_string(url)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 161, in image_to_string
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
  File "c:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

why I cant get the image ?
is there any access rights or something ?
It can be showed with this Code:

```
  url="temp.png"
  cv2.imshow("temp_photo",url)
```

I want to know why `PIL` cannot get the image ?

With the knowledge that this image can be opened with photo viewer also
So Any one can Help Me?

Comment: You can [convert between numpy and PIL images](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1095878/3962537) without having to go through a file. Otherwise, some issue with current path getting changed? What if you use an absolute path for the file name?

Comment: What's the entire backtrace you get with that error? Could this be a [duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131304/pytesseract-error-message-windowserror-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-fi)?

Comment: Yeah, you're mixing things up because you both open the image and invoke tesseract in one statement. This is a problem with pytesseract being unable to run the tesseract binary. Definitely a duplicate.

Comment: Please update your question with 1) the complete script (so we can see what's on line 25), and 2) those backtraces, properly formatted, so they are readable? Then clean up all those excess comments, this is becoming a bit of a mess. But the error is again coming from the place where you invoke tesseract, not from where you open the image.

Comment: Ok, so now it should be clear that the problem is with pytesseract unable to finding the tesseract binary, and not PIL.