# How to use neural nets to recognize handwritten digits

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, image-recognition, mnist

I followed a tutorial for creating a simple neural network using signoidal function "[Using neural nets to recognize handwritten digits](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html)", the tutorial is very simple with theory and code examples.

The problem is that it does not give any examples of digits recognition using [network.py](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/network.py).

For example, I have the following number and I want to recognize it as 0 from the image below
[image]
What should I do next for number recognition?

To make recognition of number requires the use of other technologies such as theano or tensorflow?
Good day!

Comment: But where is the example of digit recognizer from image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building upon the example below, you can add a function for prediction in the `NeuralNetwork` class:

```
def predict(self, image):
    return np.argmax(self.__feedforward(image.astype(bool).astype(int)))
```

Once you've trained your neural network successfully, you can predict an unknown digit with upto 97% accuracy with:

```
prediction = NN.predict(image)
```

---

> Excerpted from [Neural Networks - Getting Started: A Simple ANN with Python](https://web.archive.org/web/20171006220445/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/machine-learning/2709/neural-networks/9069/getting-started-a-simple-ann-with-python#t=201710062204455635968). The original authors were [cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/c%E1%B4%8F%CA%9F%E1%B4%85s%E1%B4%98%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%85) and [dontloo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3041068/dontloo). Attribution details can be found on the [contributor page](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/9069). The source is licenced under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and may be found in the [Documentation archive](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). Reference topic ID: 2709 and example ID: 9069.

The code listing below attempts to classify handwritten digits from the MNIST dataset. The digits look like this:

[image: MNIST]

The code will preprocess these digits, converting each image into a 2D array of 0s and 1s, and then use this data to train a neural network with upto 97% accuracy (50 epochs).

```
"""
Deep Neural Net 

(Name: Classic Feedforward)

"""

import numpy as np
import pickle, json
import sklearn.datasets
import random
import time
import os

# cataloguing the various activation functions and their derivatives

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-z))

def sigmoid_prime(z):
    return sigmoid(z) * (1 - sigmoid(z))

def relU(z):
    return np.maximum(z, 0, z)

def relU_prime(z):
    return z * (z <= 0)

def tanh(z):
    return np.tanh(z)

def tanh_prime(z):
    return 1 - (tanh(z) ** 2)

def transform_target(y):
    t = np.zeros((10, 1))
    t[int(y)] = 1.0
    return t


class NeuralNet:

    def __init__(self, layers, learning_rate=0.05, reg_lambda=0.01):
        self.num_layers = len(layers)  

        # initialising network parameters
        self.layers = layers          
        self.biases = [np.zeros((y, 1)) for y in layers[1:]]    
        self.weights = [np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.1, size=(y, x)) 
                                       for x, y in zip(layers[:-1], layers[1:])]
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.reg_lambda = reg_lambda

        # initialising network activation function 
        self.nonlinearity = relU
        self.nonlinearity_prime = relU_prime

    def __feedforward(self, x):
        ''' Returns softmax probabilities for the output layer '''

        for w, b in zip(self.weights, self.biases):
            x = self.nonlinearity(np.dot(w, np.reshape(x, (len(x), 1))) + b)

        return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x))

    def __backpropagation(self, x, y):
        '''
        Perform the forward pass followed by backprop 
        :param x: input
        :param y: target

        '''

        weight_gradients = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
        bias_gradients = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]

        # forward pass - transform input to output softmax probabilities
        activation = x
        hidden_activations = [np.reshape(x, (len(x), 1))]
        z_list = []

        for w, b in zip(self.weights, self.biases):    
            z = np.dot(w, np.reshape(activation, (len(activation), 1))) + b
            z_list.append(z)
            activation = self.nonlinearity(z)
            hidden_activations.append(activation)

        t = hidden_activations[-1] 
        hidden_activations[-1] = np.exp(t) / np.sum(np.exp(t))   # softmax layer

        # backward pass
        delta = (hidden_activations[-1] - y) * (z_list[-1] > 0)
        weight_gradients[-1] = np.dot(delta, hidden_activations[-2].T)
        bias_gradients[-1] = delta

        for l in range(2, self.num_layers):
            z = z_list[-l]
            delta = np.dot(self.weights[-l + 1].T, delta) * (z > 0)
            weight_gradients[-l] = np.dot(delta, hidden_activations[-l - 1].T)
            bias_gradients[-l] = delta

        return (weight_gradients, bias_gradients)

    def __update_params(self, weight_gradients, bias_gradients):
        ''' Update network parameters after backprop step '''
        for i in xrange(len(self.weights)):
            self.weights[i] += -self.learning_rate * weight_gradients[i]
            self.biases[i] += -self.learning_rate * bias_gradients[i]

    def train(self, training_data, validation_data=None, epochs=10):
        ''' Train the network for `epoch` iterations '''

        bias_gradients = None
        for i in xrange(epochs):
            random.shuffle(training_data)
            inputs = [data[0] for data in training_data]
            targets = [data[1] for data in training_data]

            for j in xrange(len(inputs)):
                (weight_gradients, bias_gradients) = self.__backpropagation(inputs[j], targets[j])
                self.__update_params(weight_gradients, bias_gradients)

            if validation_data: 
                random.shuffle(validation_data)
                inputs = [data[0] for data in validation_data]
                targets = [data[1] for data in validation_data]

                for j in xrange(len(inputs)):
                    (weight_gradients, bias_gradients) = self.__backpropagation(inputs[j], targets[j])
                    self.__update_params(weight_gradients, bias_gradients)

            print("{} epoch(s) done".format(i + 1))

        print("Training done.")

    def test(self, test_data):
        test_results = [(np.argmax(self.__feedforward(x[0])), np.argmax(x[1])) for x in test_data]
        return float(sum([int(x == y) for (x, y) in test_results])) / len(test_data) * 100

    def dump(self, file):
        pickle.dump(self, open(file, "wb"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    total = 5000
    training = int(total * 0.7)
    val = int(total * 0.15)
    test = int(total * 0.15)

    mnist = sklearn.datasets.fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home='./data')

    data = zip(mnist.data, mnist.target)
    random.shuffle(data)
    data = data[:total]
    data = [(x[0].astype(bool).astype(int), transform_target(x[1])) for x in data]

    train_data = data[:training]
    val_data = data[training:training+val]
    test_data = data[training+val:]

    print "Data fetched"

    NN = NeuralNet([784, 32, 10]) # defining an ANN with 1 input layer (size 784 = size of the image flattened), 1 hidden layer (size 32), and 1 output layer (size 10, unit at index i will predict the probability of the image being digit i, where 0 <= i <= 9)  

    NN.train(train_data, val_data, epochs=5)

    print "Network trained"

    print "Accuracy:", str(NN.test(test_data)) + "%"
```

This is a self contained code sample, and can be run without any further modifications. Ensure you have `numpy` and `scikit` learn installed for your version of python.

Comment: How should I give image as argument, like this **prediction = NN.predict(open("number.png"))**?

Comment: @IsabelCariod It is no longer as simple... You'll need to convert the image into a grayscale image that can have a numpy array representation, and it has to be resized to 28 x 28 dimensions.

Comment: That is my only problem.

Comment: @IsabelCariod Your question could've been a little more pointed in this direction. :) You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42032566/4909087) to resize it. Loading the image as a matrix is also straightforward, there are many examples to do it with `PIL` in python.

Comment: Hm, very interesting @coldspeed. I didn't you were in the machine learning field! (although I guess I should have known since most numpy/pandas users seem to be ;-) )

Comment: @ChristianDean Thank you! haha yes, ML questions happen to be my favourite actually. The only reason you don't see me answering much of them is because of the low traffic. But, when I can, I do. Mostly neural network and sklearn related stuff.

Comment: @JonEricson Um, the wayback machine link goes to a different page... could you look into it please?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Fixed. Thanks for letting me know.