# Behavior of NotImpemented in comparison

Tags: python

I recently found out that python has a special value [NotImpemented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented) to be used with respect to binary special methods to indicate that some operation has not been implemented.

The peculiar about this is that when checked in a binary situation it is always equivalent to `True`.

For example using `io.BytesIO` (which is a case where `__eq__` in not implemented for example) for two objects in comparison will virtually return `True`. As in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49533095/3584765) (`encoded_jpg_io1` and `encoded_jpg_io2` are objects of the `io.BytesIO` class):

```
if encoded_jpg_io1.__ne__(encoded_jpg_io2):
    print('Equal')
else:
    print('Unequal')
```

> Equal

```
if encoded_jpg_io1.__eq__(encoded_jpg_io2) == True:
    print('Equal')
else:
    print('Unequal')
```

> Unequal

Since the second style is a bit too verbose and normally not prefered (even my pyCharm suggests to remove the explicit comparison with `True`) isn't a bit tricky behavior? I wouldn't have noticed it if I haven't explicitly print the result of the Boolean operation (which is not Boolean in this case at all).

I guess suggesting to be considered `False` would cause the same problem with `__ne__` so we arew back to step one.

So, the only way to check out for these cases is by doing an  exact comparison with `True` or `False` in the opposite case.

I know that `NotImpemented` is preferred over `NotImplementedError` for various [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878943/why-return-notimplemented-instead-of-raising-notimplementederror) so I am not asking for any explanation over why this matter.

Comment: `NotImplemented` is designed to give the correct results when you use `a==b`, not `a.__eq__(b)`. If you opt to call the `__eq__` and `__ne__` directly then you have to handle with the added complication of `NotImplemented` yourself.

Comment: So if you were to rephrase this into an actual question, it might be "Why does Python say that these objects are not equal (`!=`) instead of raising an exception?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per convention, objects that do not define a [`__bool__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) are considered truthy. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a `__bool__()` method that returns `False` or a `__len__()` method that returns zero

This means that most classes, functions, and other builtin singletons are considered true, since they don't go out of their way to specify different behavior. (An exception is `None`, which is one of the few built-in singletons that *does* specifically signal it should be considered false):

```
>>> bool(int)  # the class, not an integer object
True
>>> bool(min)
True
>>> bool(object())
True
>>> bool(...)  # that's the Ellipsis object
True
>>> bool(NotImplemented)
True
```

There is no real reason for the `NotImplemented` object to break this convention. The problem with your code isn't that `NotImplemented` is considered truthy; the real problem is that `x.__eq__(y)` is not equivalent to `x == y`.

**If you want to compare two objects for equality, doing it with `x.__eq__(y)` is incorrect. Using `x.__eq__(y) == True` instead is still incorrect.**

The correct solution is to do comparison with the `==` operator. If, for whatever reason, you can't use the `==` operator directly, you should use the [`operator.eq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.eq) function instead.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry, but I'm not a fan of that edit. That's a bit too technical; I don't want venture that deep into python's inner workings. I think it's enough (and not incorrect) to say that *"`None` is explicitly defined to be falsy"*, without going into details about how that's implemented. Whether it has a `__bool__` method or not is really besides the point. I'm rolling it back.

Comment: Then why bring up the None special case at all? It has no externally visible effect now that `None` has a `__bool__` method, and `None` isn't even the only special-cased object; [`True` and `False` are also special-cased](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Objects/object.c#L1225).

Comment: @user2357112 That's all specifically about CPython's implementation though. The point I'm trying to make is that `None` is well-defined to be falsy in the python language because it's commonly used in a boolean context, whereas other objects like `NotImplemented` are _not_ meant or designed to be used in a boolean context and therefore default to the standard behavior of being truthy. (So yes, `True` and `False` are also exceptions, but I don't think it's necessary to mention that booleans have a well-defined truth value...)

Comment: None is defined to be false, but not in a way that makes it an exception from the general rules. Your answer acts as if it's an exception.

Comment: @user2357112 Again, it's not about _how_ `None` gets its truth value. I'm arguing on a higher level here; it's about language semantics. The simple fact that the truth value of `None` is _explicitly_ stated in the documentation makes it different from `NotImplemented` or the ellipsis object or `int` or `min`.

Comment: I'd remove the mention of `None` from the answer, but I'm sure someone would well-actually me in the comments if I did... :p