# JPG image into matrix using Python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

How to convert an image with `.jpg` format into a matrix of pixels using Python (NumPy).

I have searched the internet but I can't find a way to use Python; most of the results in the search use Matlab, but I want to do it with Python.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384759/how-to-convert-a-pil-image-into-a-numpy-array . Did this help?

Comment: `pic = Image.open("foo.jpg")`  `pix = numpy.array(pic)`

Comment: `ArrayYouWant=numpy.array(Image.open("someImage.jpg"))`