# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Image' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I wanted to convert the PIL Image object into a numpy array. I tried using the following codes it showing an error

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-133-0898103f22f0> in <module>()
      1 image_path = 'test/28/image_05230.jpg'
----> 2 image = process_image(image_path)
      3 imshow(image)

<ipython-input-129-e036faebfd31> in process_image(image_path)
     24     # normalize
     25     print(type(image))
---> 26     image_arr = np.array(image) / 255
     27     mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
     28     std_dv = np.array( [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Image' and 'int'
```

---

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(image_path)
image = np.asarray(image) / 255
```

I also tried with this code **image = np.array(image) / 255** it's showing the same error. (code below)

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(image_path)
image = np.array(image) / 255
```

This error occurs only when I used the above code in below function

```
def convert_pil_to_numpy_array(image_path):
    # Load Image an open the image
    from PIL import Image

    image = Image.open(image_path)
    width = image.size[0]
    height = image.size[1]

    if width > height:
      image.thumbnail((500, 256))
    else:
      image.thumbnail((256, 500))

    left_margin = (image.width - 224) / 2
    lower_margin = (image.height - 224) / 2
    upper_margin = lower_margin + 224
    right_margin = left_margin + 224

    image = image.crop((left_margin, upper_margin, right_margin, lower_margin))

    # normalize
    print(type(image))
    image_arr = np.array(image) / 255
    mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
    std_dv = np.array( [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    image_arr = (image_arr - mean)/std_dv

    return image_arr
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner Actually I wanted to convert the Image type into numpy array and then divide whole elements in that array with 255

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384759/how-to-convert-a-pil-image-into-a-numpy-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a PIL Image into a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384759/how-to-convert-a-pil-image-into-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Nope! It's not the same.... I have tried not working @TomRon

Comment: It works, I tested with a test image..can you show the Traceback error?

Comment: `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-b49e38963fe0> in <module>()
      1 image_path = 'test/10/image_07090.jpg'
----> 2 image = process_image(image_path)
      3 imshow(image)

<ipython-input-123-88f9e8458c48> in process_image(image_path)
     24     # normalize
     25     print(type(image))
---> 26     image = np.array(image) / 255
     27     mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
     28     std_dv = np.array( [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Image' and 'int'` @amanb

Comment: How about you `print(image)` first and see if you get an array first? Refer to my answer below.

Comment: Please add the *formatted* traceback to the question; it's nearly unreadable as a comment.

Comment: @chepner I've added

Comment: @amanb It's of type `<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=224x0 at 0x7F0A12C6EA58>` after doing this `image_arr = np.array(image)`

Comment: Your traceback doesn't match your code; it refers to `np.array`, but you call `np.asarray`. I would expect that `np.array` simply creates an array that *contains* an image as its single element, not an array that *represents* an image as an array of pixels.

Comment: ok, just edited my answer. I've used `array` function but `asarray` also works.

Comment: @amanb Both `np.array` & `np.asarray` gives same error. I have mentioned that.

Comment: My answer explains the problem..please take a look. It works.

Comment: `np.asarray` is just `np.array` with the `copy=False` parameter set.  It shouldn't make any difference here.

Comment: The Traceback error shows `process_image()` function and a `image_arr` variable. Your code does not have these.

Comment: @amanb Please have a look at my code... I have added a function where it's not working

Comment: @KavinRajuS, just edited my answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you presented the *real* code you are actually using:

- `Image.open("path.jpg")` returns `<class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>`
- after your cropping you get a return of `<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>`

If you inspect your cropped `image`, you can see it only has one dimension, the second is 0:

[image: Debugger picture]

If you fix your code to:

```
def convert_pil_to_numpy_array(image_path):
    # Load Image an open the image
    from PIL import Image

    image = Image.open(image_path)
    width = image.size[0]
    height = image.size[1] 

    image.thumbnail((500, 256) if (width > height) else (256, 500))  

    left_margin = (image.width - 224) / 2
    upper_margin = (image.height - 224) / 2     # fixed
    lower_margin = upper_margin + 224           # fixed
    right_margin = left_margin + 224

    # fixed and renamed so you do not overwrite image all the time - helps debugging
    # now this has 2 dimensions that are non-zero
    image_crop = image.crop((left_margin, upper_margin, right_margin, lower_margin))

    # normalize
    image_arr = np.asarray(image) / 255
    mean = np.mean(image_arr)
    std_dv = np.std( image_arr )
    image_arr = (image_arr - mean)/std_dv 

    return image_crop
```

the code suddenly runs without errors.

Comment: Thank you for helping @patrich artner.... Actually, I had found this error and corrected the code...

Answer (score 3):

In the function `convert_pil_to_numpy_array()`, the `image` variable used initially is different from the `image` variable that stores the `crop`ped `Image` object.

```
from PIL import Image
image_path = "C:\\temp\\Capture.JPG"
image = Image.open(image_path)
print(type(image))
#Output
<class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>
```

This is a `JpegImageFile` object. If you look at the other `image` variable that stores the cropped image and is later passed to `np.array`, this variable is an object of the `Image` class:

```
image = image.crop((left_margin, upper_margin, right_margin, lower_margin))
print(type(image))
#Output:
<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
```

The problem lies in the tuple values passed to the `crop()` function. With the margin values that you passed to `crop`, the image could not be converted to an array and returned an `Image` object again:

```
image_arr = np.array(image)
print(image_arr)
#Output:
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=224x0 at 0x39E4F60>
```

As your image dimensions were different from mine, I used different values for the 4-tuple passed to `crop()` and got an array:

```
image = image.crop((50,100,60,120))
image_arr = np.array(image)
#Output:
  [[[-2.11790393 -2.03571429 -1.80444444]
  [-2.11790393 -2.03571429 -1.80444444]
  [-2.11790393 -2.03571429 -1.80444444]
  [-2.11790393 -2.03571429 -1.80444444]
  [-2.11790393 -2.03571429 -1.80444444]
  [-2.11790393 -2.03571429 -1.80444444]
  [-2.11790393 -2.03571429 -1.80444444]
  [-2.11790393 -2.03571429 -1.80444444]
  [-2.11790393 -2.03571429 -1.80444444]
  [-2.11790393 -2.03571429 -1.80444444]]..etc
```

What you should do is, check the margin values and save the cropped image to file(jpg, png, etc.) and then convert to array. Note that I am not storing the saved image to any variable. :

```
image.crop((50, 60, 100, 120)).save("test.jpg")
image_arr = np.array(Image.open("test.jpg")) / 255
mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
std_dv = np.array( [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
image_arr = (image_arr - mean)/std_dv
print(image_arr)
#Output:
  [[[-0.04580872  0.08263305  0.30448802]
  [-0.91917116 -0.81022409 -0.58440087]
  [ 0.81042898  0.95798319  1.17594771]
  ...
  [ 2.19753404  2.37605042  2.58771242]
  [-0.02868396 -0.19747899  0.13019608]
  [-0.11430773 -0.28501401  0.04305011]]
  ....etc.
```

Comment: I don't see how your code is any better.  `np.array(image)` should create an array just like your line.  Only after is run does Python apply the `/255` step.

Comment: I agree, I just tested OP's code and the `/255` step applies after. But the exact same piece of code works for me. This answer suggests to check if the array is created in the first place and if so, save it in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open(r'C:\temp\2015-05-14 17.43.10.jpg') # path to existing local file
image_arr = np.asarray(image) / 255

print(image_arr)
```

Output:

```
[[[ 0.35294118  0.39607843  0.41960784]
  [ 0.38039216  0.42352941  0.44705882]
  [ 0.41568627  0.45098039  0.47058824]
  ...,
  [ 0.05490196  0.04705882  0.05098039]
  [ 0.04705882  0.03921569  0.04313725]
  [ 0.04313725  0.03529412  0.03921569]]

 [[ 0.36470588  0.4         0.42745098]
  [ 0.38823529  0.42352941  0.44313725]
  [ 0.40784314  0.44313725  0.4627451 ]
  ..., etc ]
```