# Trying to resize the frame to fit into a model

Tags: python

I need help, I am trying to resize the frame_img (224, 224) to fit into the model because I am using a pretrained model which is MobileNetV2, below is the error and the code;

```
#frame_img = frame[y:x+y1,x:x+x1]
    123         #print(frame_img)
--> 124         image = imutils.resize(frame_img, (224,224)) #resizing the frame to fit into the model
    125         image = img_to_array(image) #converting the resized frame to array
    126         image = preprocess_input(image)
```

```
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\imutils\convenience.py in resize(image, width, height, inter)
     85         # calculate the ratio of the width and construct the
     86         # dimensions
---> 87         r = width / float(w)
     88         dim = (width, int(h * r))
     89 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'float'
```

```
frame_img = frame[y:y1,x:x1]
    #frame_img = frame[y:x+y1,x:x+x1]
    #print(frame_img)
    image = imutils.resize(frame_img, (224,224)) #resizing the frame to fit into the model
    image = img_to_array(image) #converting the resized frame to array
    image = preprocess_input(image) 
    image = expand_dim(image, axis=0) #expanding the dimension to fit in the model
    pred = mask_model.predict(image) #making predictions on the on the image
    result = tf.nn.softmax(prediction[0])
```

Comment: Please include the libraries that you are using.

Comment: Also, please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does this answer your query [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54011487/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-image-and-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message it looks like the `resize(image, width, height, inter)` function expects the parameters, `image`, `width`, `height`, and `inter`.

The code you've provided looks like you are passing in a tuple as the second parameter.

Try changing it to:

```py
    ...
    image = imutils.resize(frame_img, 224, 224)
    ...
```