# What does this third argument of reshape mean?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384759/how-to-convert-a-pil-image-into-a-numpy-array) about numpy, array and reshape. I understand what the OP is doing and his line of code, except the last argument of reshape: `3`

According to the documentation of [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape), the third argument of the function is the `order` and should be a string {'C', 'F', 'A'}, optional.

So what does the OP argument `3` means?

Side note: In the question, OP places `3` as **second** argument because it is the function `numpy.array.reshape`, while in the documentation of `numpy.reshape` the order is the **third** argument. But it is because in `numpy.reshape` the array itself is the first argument.

The `numpy.array.reshape` documentation page redirects to `numpy.reshape` page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong version of `reshape`. The relevant one is [`ndarray.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape) which

> allows the elements of the shape parameter to be passed in as separate arguments

Therefore,

```
a = np.array(...)
a.reshape(3, 4, 5)
```

is like doing

```
np.reshape(a, (3, 4, 5))
```

---

In the original question, the `3` is simply a part of the reshape operation since the OP is trying to work with an RGB image as a 3D array of shape `(height, width, 3)`

Comment: In the side note of the question, I do explain that I noticed that, except that I have called "ndarray.reshape" as "nupy.array.reshape"

Comment: The `3` is just part of specifying the shape for the reshape operation

Comment: But the shape has already been explained in the example by len(X) and len(Y). What does the parameter 3 mean ?

Comment: They are trying to reshape the data for a color image so the 3 corresponds to the depth of the array/image i.e. the RGB channels.

Comment: Ok so that mean that three arrays are handled for one picture, ie one array for each of the RGB channels?

Comment: Better to think of it as 1 array which is of shape (height, width, 3), so essentially 3 single color frames stacked on top of each other

Comment: Ok I get it
Maybe you can give an answer with this discussion of comments and I will accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code, which runs as expected:

```
arr = np.arange(12) # arr has 12 element
arr = np.reshape(arr, (3, 4)) 

print(arr) # prints '[[ 0  1  2  3] [ 4  5  6  7] [ 8  9 10 11]]'
```

Now, consider this code which has an error in it:

```
arr = np.arange(24) # arr has 24 element

# next line will fail, because (3, 4) can only have 12 element... but 'arr' has 24 element
arr = np.reshape(arr, (3, 4)) 

print(arr)
```

What can we do to solve it?

A solution would be, to have 3 parents `list`  inside the main list, where each parent `list` has a structure of `(4, 2)`. So together these 3 parents `list` can hold `8 * 3` or `24` items. That's why the next block of code runs without any error.

```
arr = np.arange(24) # arr has 24 element

arr = np.reshape(arr, (3, 4, 2))  # 3 means it will have 3 parent list that has a structure of (4, 2)

print(arr) # prints '[  [[ 0  1] [ 2  3] [ 4  5] [ 6  7]]    [[ 8  9] [10 11] [12 13] [14 15]]    [[16 17] [18 19] [20 21] [22 23]]  ]'
```