# python "can't assign to comparison" error

Tags: python, image, filter, assign, ycbcr

I want single YCbCr-channels that are smaller or bigger that 128 of a picture set to 0.
But I keep getting the error "can't assign to comparison" and I don't really know what I am doing wrong.

This is the code:

```
def calc_coloursplash(image_data, modus):
    ycbcr = image_data.convert('YCbCr')

    if modus == 1:
        ycbcr[:,:,1] <= 128 = 0
        ycbcr[:,:,2] <= 128 = 0
    elif modus == 2:
        ycbcr[:,:,1] >= 128 = 0
        ycbcr[:,:,2] <= 128 = 0
    elif modus == 3:
        ycbcr[:,:,1] >= 128 = 0
        ycbcr[:,:,2] >= 128 = 0
    elif modus == 4:
        ycbcr[:,:,1] <= 128 = 0
        ycbcr[:,:,2] >= 128 = 0
    else:
        print("There are only modes 1-4")

    return ycbcr
```

And this picture shows the different modes I implemented:

[image]

Comment: `ycbcr[:,:,1] <= 128` is a comparison; `ycbcr[:,:,1] <= 128 = 0` is trying to assign 0 to it.

Comment: Okay I got that. And how can I assign zero to all values under 128?

Answer (score 1):

you can use np.where:

```
ycbcr[:,:,1][np.where(ycbcr[:,:,1]<128)]=0
```

Comment: Thanks, but then it shows me "image object is not subscriptable" as an error

Comment: i think you use the PIl package.
you can use:
    a = np.array(a)
from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384759/how-to-convert-a-pil-image-into-a-numpy-array

Comment: I'm just doing ```image = Image.open("ahab.jpg")``` and then  ```ycbcr = image.convert('YCbCr')```. Could it be the wrong way of loading the image?