# How to make grayscale image using numpy and matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing

I want to make a grayscale image but getting errors like this, I have already searched on google but don't get the answer and I don't know what keywords I should use to search it on google.

My Code:

```
!pip install matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = plt.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/gambar.jpg')
img = np.zeros([120, 300, 3], dtype=np.uint8)

h, w = img[:2]

for x in range(w):
  for y in range(h):
    gray = (20 + 125 + 255) / 3
    img[y,x] = gray

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Errors Output:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-e6c1f87f1234> in <module>()
      8 h, w = img[:2]
      9 
---> 10 for x in range(w):
     11   for y in range(h):
     12     gray = (20 + 125 + 255) / 3

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: None of your code makes any sense. Read a tutorial please. [ask]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201577/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-into-grayscale-in-python). The accepted answer shows doing this with both Pillow and numpy/matplotlib.

If the end goal is just to save the image out as a grayscale version then Pillow will do the job. If the goal is to send the grayscale version to some other part of the script where numpy/matplotlib is required you can either use the second part of the answer at the above link or convert the Pillow object to a numpy array as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384759/how-to-convert-a-pil-image-into-a-numpy-array).